# Is BufferedReader needed to read from file?

Tags: java

There's this code 
`Reader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("large_file.txt")))` to read the whole file one character at a time. Is `BufferedReader` really needed or the `FileReader` and OS disk cache will do a good job of buffering?

UPD. Did a little test on a Mac Mini with SSD and 4Gb of RAM. The file is in something similar to CSV parsed by a hand-written FSM parser. Using `BufferedReader` is roughly two times faster for both small (50Mb) and large (1Gb) files.

Comment: It is not fundamentally needed, but then you can also read a single character. However, this is 2015, so please use `Files.newBufferedReader()` instead -- and specify the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Measure it. To some degree you are right: there is a redundancy, but still a BufferedReader helps speed up, especially for large files. One factor is that less native calls are made.

Also ritually the buffer size is a power of 2, so OS buffer sizes will fit better. Also I would refrain from small sizes like 128 B.

Alternatively one might use memory mapped I/O, a `ByteBuffer`.

As to the APIs (though in your case probably not applicable):

```
Path path = Paths.get("large_file.txt");

byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String text = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

or

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```